# why this ionic alert code is not working using angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

```
async presentAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Alert',
      subHeader: 'Subtitle',
      message: 'This is an alert message.',
      buttons: ['OK'],
    });

    await alert.present();
    let result = await alert.onDidDismiss();
    console.log(result);
  }
```

and my html is

```
  <div class="about-button">
                <ion-button (click)="presentAlert()">About</ion-button>
              </div>
```

How will this work?
It is not working that is on clicking button nothing happens.
My ionic version is 5.4.5
and tried also for ionic 4

Comment: its work fine in ionic 4

Comment: No its not . may be I am missing something important?  Also my version is ionic 5 .. does version matter?

Comment: i am trying with your code, its work. but i think version 5 so, this issue come

Comment: What error are you getting??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually everything was correct. I just had 2 app-root in my app.html. This was not enabling it to show.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, use await only one time.
You can have a button that on the close of the alert can handle the data.

```
   const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      inputs: [
        {
         name: 'name1',
         type: 'text'
        }],    
      buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Cancel',
              role: 'cancel',
             cssClass: 'secondary',
              handler: () => {
               console.log('Confirm Cancel');
             }
            }, {
              text: 'Ok',
              handler: (alertData) => { //takes the data 
                console.log(alertData.name1);
            }
            }
          ]
   });
  await alert.present();
```